# How to I create a user that is allowed to only add/remove users to distribution lists in Active Directory?

Tags: active-directory, domain, domain-controller

I do have a third party product (Jira) that has Active Directory integration via LDAP.

I want to enable Jira administrators to edit group memberships and have them syncronized inside Active Directory.

This currently works but I needed to use a Domain Administrator service account in order to do this.

The question is how can I do this without giving the entire Domain Administrator permission to the service account.

Answer (score 3):

You can [delegate administration](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc778807%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) to your service account in order to allow it to edit group membership, without giving it full Domain Admin rights. This can be done for a single group, for all groups in give OU, or for all groups in the whole domain,

http://www.windowsecurity.com/articles/Implementing-Active-Directory-Delegation-Administration.html